# The use of past continuous

Tags: past-continuous

I know that we use past simple for repeated actions for instance: 'when I was little I went to that school' or 'I worked in that firm for three years' and saying 'I was working in that firm for three years' when I just want to state a fact. Is that wrong or not?

I also know that saying  'when I was working she came to me', this past continuous is justified because it creates the background.    What about 'when I was working for three years she came to me'. Is using past continuous here justified too for background information?

Comment: Please leave some space between sentences some of those sentences.

Comment: What do you intend the sentence to mean? 'During the three years that I worked there' or 'After I had worked there for three years'?

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is close, and would work if you were talking about a pet, whose action of "coming" was significant, but the qualifier usually goes last, as in:
"she came to me while I was working"
"she came to me whenever I was working"

For a person, you'd want to elaborate on why she came to you, as in:
"she came to see me while I was working"
"she came to talk to me while I was working"

For time related qualifiers, it's a bit different:
"she came to talk to me after I had been working for three years"
"she came to see me after I had been at the office for an hour"
"she came to see me just after I got to the office"